# Quorum for chazaras hashatz

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, minyan

How many people are needed in order to start chazaras hashatz?

Comment: As many people that finish before the rabbi of the shul finishes :)

Answer (score 8):

The opinion of the Shulchan Aruch, Orah Haim, *Siman* 124, *S'if* 4 is that 9 men answering is required, **but** the  Mishnah Berurah (S'if Katan 19) brings down from Magen Avraham and the Maharil (Ashkenazic authorities) that the common custom is to use even those who are not listening to complete the minyan (which would mean 6 listening and 3 not listening). The Mishnah B'rurah suggests the Shaliah Tzibbur make a condition that if there are not 9 listening it should be a *T'filas N'davah* in order to take the *Bais Yosef*'s opinion into consideration. This would imply that one should wait until there are 9 men who **can** respond, but Rav Feurst told me that Reb Moshe Feinstein told him that 6 men was enough (of course all of this is provided that there are a total of ten men there).

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=294&hilite=

Comment: On the other hand, Shulchan Aruch Harav (even though he often follows Magen Avraham) does not do so in this case: he states flatly (55:7 and 124:6) that there must be nine men listening and responding Amen.

Comment: Yes, the Rav's Shulhan Aruch and the Hayei Adam are in agreement on this. Every Shul should follow its Rav and Mesorah.

Comment: That last sentence is of course true, and I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. I wonder, though, given that both of these sources seem to (uncharacteristically) ignore the M"A and Maharil, whether indeed the Mishnah Berurah really means that he endorses this position, or whether he's just using it as a limud zechus.

Answer (score 5):

There need to be at least nine men who are able to answer Amen to his blessings (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 124:4).

Comment: Is there any legitimate reason behind those people who only wait for seven?

Comment: There have to have been at least 6 people who prayed the silent Amidah together (the other four can just be bystanders). But no, I don't know a source that says that just seven responders is enough.

Comment: Tzvi, see my answer. The number seven is the Shaliah Tzibbur plus 6 who will answer based on the Magen Avraham and the Maharil.

Comment: Alex, what is the  source for what you wrote that there must be at least 6 who prayed together in order to have Hazaras Hashatz?

Comment: See Orach Chaim 55:6 and Magen Avraham ibid. :8 citing Ralbach. This is in turn cited in Shulchan Aruch Harav 55:7.

Comment: @Alex Maybe I'm being too medayek, but it seems from your answer that the 9 wouldn't have to answer, just that they should be able to. That's not right, is it?

Comment: @HodofHod, that diyuk certainly escaped me. You're right, they have to actually answer.

Comment: Would this number be affected by the concept of Shome'a K'oneh? Is it as if they are answering? If so, why wait for anyone if all those still davening will pause for kedusha (according to certain opinions)?

Answer (score 0):

The Mishna Berura in sif katan 19 seems to be referring to a case where the people have the ability to answer, just they are not answering or possibly not answering, to the repetition. However, if you only have six who finished the quiet shemoneh esrei and thus you cannot possibly have nine answering it does not seem clear the Mishnah Berura would agree that the shliach tzibur can start the repetition.