# Why for repetition of Shomne Esray you need only 6 that prayed but 9 that will answer?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, number, shemoneh-esrei, minyan

I was asked the following question:

For the repetition of the Shemone Esray, you need only **6** to finish praying to begin the repetition.

However, there must be **9** people answering Amen to the blessings. Why?

What can I answer him?

Comment: [edit]ing in sources for those numbers would greatly improve this question.

Comment: @Shokhet that is what i want to research this for now i have siman 69 and 124 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/quorum-for-chazaras-hashatz

Answer (score 1):

Tefillo K'hilchoso 13 (27) says (my translation)

> Ideally (lechatchilo) one should not start the repetition of the
>   amidah with less than 9 excluding the prayer leader (from the
>   expression in Sh O 124 (1)), because if there are not 9 listening the
>   blessings of the prayer leader are close to being in vain (levatolo). 
>   But there are those who are lenient and allow the repetition with 7 or
>   even 6 who have finished (Mogein Avrohom 55 (8)).

This information is very similar to the answer to [Quorum for chazaras hashatz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/quorum-for-chazaras-hashatz?lq=1) because the question is very similar to that question.

The answer to the person who asked the OP is therefore:

The first statement in the question goes according to the lenient view.

The second statement goes according to the ideal view.

Comment: So I can say that 6 is bidieved (they already davened) and 9 is lichatchila (we should not start until we have 9)?

Comment: Yes indeed that's it.